# Office 365 -- sheet view

Tags: office365, microsoft-excel-365

When you add a filter to Excel 365 file opened in a browser (not in a desktop app) there is a menu item called "Sheet View", but it is grayed out.

[image]

I wonder if it is something similar to Google spreadsheet's feature called filter view. If it is, how can I enable it?

The only relevant information I was able to found is [this](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-for-the-web/suggestions/8192445-allow-for-personal-user-views-filters)

It states that the work on this feature has been started. Is it grayed out because it is still work in progress?

Answer (score 0):

Sheet Views are indeed the Microsoft Excel implementation of Google's Filter views. You can create new views in OneDrive- or SharePoint-hosted Excel files by clicking on the View tab on the Ribbon, and then selecting the "New" option:

[image: Depiction of the Sheet View options]

This feature is not available in the desktop version of Excel or anywhere you have Excel set to require a check out for editing. It requires the collaborative/multiple concurrent user features of Excel Online.